# Is there a way to set TimeZone only for a specific class or method?

Tags: java, spring, timezone

I inherited the code developed by my predecessor.

I put the code I developed here, but the time problem occurs because of TimeZone.

The problem is that if you set TimeZone globally, it is predicted that there will be problems in the existing code.

So I want to set TimeZone only for my code

Is there a way to specify Timezone only in my class file or my method?

First of all, my web server operates based on UTC, and existing codes are also based on that standard.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
```

Using this, my webserver is pointed to Asia/Seoul and I get the time I want.

However, since this is set globally, there is concern that code written in UTC will have problems.

So it cannot be used.

Also `LocalDateTime.now(Zone...);` I can get the results I want by using .

However, the zone should be reflected in the already created (DB) time, not now.

In other words, 2022-06-17 15:00 is considered my time as 2022-06-18 00:00.

Rather than specifying +09:00 directly, I want a way that 2022-06-17 15:00 with TimeZone etc can be considered as 2022-06-18 00:00 by the server.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question unless you can show us the code that you're worried about.

Comment: FYI, `TimeZone` is one of the tragically flawed legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically, replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`. If you shared actual code, or a simplified contrived version of your code, we could show you how to solve your conundrum while converting back and forth between the legacy and modern classes.

Comment: Edited the content. Can you check again?

Comment: I still don’t see the class or method for which you want your time zone to apply. So all we can say is: yes, for time zone sensitive operations it is generally possible to specify time zone.

Answer (score 1):

LocaDate.now allow with zone id.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-

If its date use zone Id  date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("")).toLocalDateTime()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--

Use Instant and zone id

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2022-06-18 00:00");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");
LocalDateTime value LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Intent and cause of the question

The time in UTC is entered in the DB.
time : 2022-06-17 15:00

I wanted to convert this to Asia time in a Zoned `LocalDateTime`.
(+09:00 is required.)

The time I want: 2022-06-18 00:00

However, no matter which method was used, the time in UTC standard was output as it is.

`getMyTime.atZone(...).toLocalDateTime ..`
Output: 2022-06-17 15:00

While looking for a way, I found that LocalDateTime ignores (or deletes) the "zone" information.

When creating time, it can be created with zone information, but zone information has no meaning after it has already been created.

#### The solution

From then on, I got closer to the answer, and I found it.

```
ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime,ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul"))
        .toLocalDateTime();
```

Get the zoneDateTime of the base time.

and the key

Create an instant with zone information through `withZoneSameInstant` and create it as `LocalDateTime`.

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: You don’t need to convert to `LocalDateTime`.  Keeping a `ZonedDateTime`, an object that “knows” itself that it is in Asia/Seoul time zone, is advantageous.

Comment: Unfortunately, many sources that used to work with LocalDateTime in other projects have been moved to this project, so we have to keep this form.

Personally, I think I will use ZonedDateTime rather than LocalDateTime in the future.

Comment: Are you saying that your project is full of instances of `LocalDateTime` that should have been some other class, such as `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`?  I  think there's a lesson here.  The whole point of the Java 8 date and time classes is to allow you to make a distinction in your code between the date and time on a calendar and clock (a `LocalDateTime`), an actual moment in time (an `Instant`), and a time where you know the time zone (a `ZonedDateTime`).  These are three very different things.  It sounds like  someone has picked the wrong one in the past, and created a disaster for you ...

Comment: ... to fix.  Be very careful not to repeat their error.  Make sure you know the difference between these three classes, and always pick the right one.